# Finding wages of each worker

Tags: ratio

A, B and C undertake to do a piece of work for Rs.1950. A work for 8 days, B for 9 days and C for 12 days to complete the work. If their daily wages are in the ratio of 3:5:4 , What does C get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daily wages are in the ratio 3 : 5 : 4

Working days of A, B and C = 8, 9 and 12

So the wages they get will be in ratio

$3 \times 8 : 5 \times 9: 4 \times 12$

= 24 : 45 : 48

Share of C

= $\frac{48}{(24+45+48)} \times 1950 = 800$

Answer (score 0):

The relative wages of A,B and C are $8\cdot 3$, $9\cdot 5$ and $12\cdot 4$.

The ratio of the relative wage of C and the sum of all relative wages is

$r=\frac{12\cdot 4}{8\cdot 3+9\cdot 5+12\cdot 4}=\frac{16}{39}$

This is the porportion what $C$ gets from $Rs.1950$.